# Minimal graphics installation

Tags: system-installation, gui, ubuntu-minimal

Is possible to install Ubuntu Desktop by minimal installation (no additional programs like firefox etc), but with GUI installation? Because i found Minimal CD, but it supports only command line installation and text-based. I am looking for native GUI Ubuntu Desktop installation, but without pre installed apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this from a graphical user interface, you have to do it from command line.
You can install the Ubuntu server edition and install a desktop environment on that afterwards.
But this is not recommended for users without some more advanced knowledge how to do it ...
It is much easier to install the Ubuntu desktop edition and remove the unwanted applications.

Comment: Yes i know :) thank you, but i replied to your comment yesterday, you can check it :) it is at ask about performance ubuntu 14 vs 15